# How to resolve the error from a promise in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am in need of guidance with getting through this error. The code is supposed to get the results from WebAPI while going through actions and services. In the actions is a dispatch where the error is. On my actions page it should call the service for WebAPI and depend on the response dispatch to the reducers for actions. The code does not pass the first dispatch in the jobActions.getjobs()

The error received from this is:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _actions_job_actions__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.jobActions.getJobs(...).then is not a function

```
Page Load
import React from 'react';
import { jobActions } from '../../actions/job.actions';

class LoadTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],
        }
    }
         componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getJobs()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({ data: res.response || [] })
            });
    }
render() {
return ();
}
 const mapDispatchToProps => dispatch => ({ getJobs: () => dispatch(jobActions.getJobs()) });
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)( LoadTable );  
===============================================
Actions
import { jobConstants } from '../constants/job.constants';
import { jobService } from '../services/job.service';

export const jobActions = {
    getJobs
};
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
function getJobs() {     
    return dispatch => {        
        dispatch(request());
        return jobService.getJobs()
            .then(
                results => {                    
                    dispatch(success(user));
                    return { results };
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error));
                }
            );
    };
    function request() { return { type: jobConstants.JOB_REQUEST }; }
    function success(user) { return { type: jobConstants.JOB_SUCCESS, user }; }
    function failure(error) { return { type: jobConstants.JOB_FAILURE, error }; }
 }

=======================================================
services
export const jobService = {
  getJobs
};

const handleResponseToJson = res => res.json();
function getJobs() {

    return fetch('http://localhost:53986/api/jobs/getoutput')
        .then(handleResponseToJson)
        .then(response => {
            if (response) {
                return { response };
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
}
```

The result should be table data from the services page, actions page dispatching depending on the stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using some sort of a middleware, like redux-thunk? If not, then your action creator returns a function, which is not supported by pure redux

I guess you do, because the error says that the action creator returned undefined after it was called

```js
    function getJobs() {    
    console.log("test -1");
    return dispatch => {
        console.log("test-2");
        dispatch(request());
        jobService.getJobs()  // <==== here comes the promise, that you don't return
     // return jobService.getJobs()  <== this is the solution
            .then(
                results => {
                    console.log("test -3");
                    dispatch(success(user));
                    return { results };
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error));
                }
            );
    };
```

Update: you also need to map your action in mapDispatchToProps

```
Page Load
import React from 'react';
import { jobActions } from '../../actions/job.actions';

class LoadTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],
        }
    }
     componentDidMount() {
       this.props.getJobs() // as the name of mapDispatchToProps says, you mapped your action dispatch
                            // to a getJobs prop, so now you just need call it
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.response || []
                })            
            }));      
    }

render() {
return ();
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // this function will dispatch your action, but it also mapps it to a new prop - getJobs
  getJobs: () => dispatch(jobActions.getJobs()) 
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)( LoadTable );
```

Comment: Ah yes, I am using redux-think, So essentially have another return prior to the JobService call.

Comment: I tried it, and still have the same error. Do you believe that I need to add something on the initial call in the Component Mount?

Comment: Have you mapped that action call in mapDispatchToProps() ? Because if not, then you need to manually dispatch it like instead of calling it directly `jobActions.getJobs().then(() => ...)`, you need to dispatch it `dispatch(jobActions.getJobs()).then(() => ...)`

Comment: No let me map it in the initial call and update the code

Comment: `const mapDispatchToProps => dispatch => ({ getJobs: () => dispatch(jobActions.getJobs()) });`

Comment: and then you call it in `componentDidUpdate` as `this.props.getJobs().then(() => ...)`

Comment: And don't forget to add that `return` for the jobService.getJobs() inside your action creator

Comment: I updated the code. Is that what you had in mind above?

Comment: yes, except that I probably mislead you a bit there. You have both, componentDidUpdate and componentDidMount. I meant, that you should edit your componentDidMount function, not add the componentDidUpdate. Sorry about that, it was my typo. Your resulting componentDidMount should look like this: ```componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getJobs()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.response || []
                })            
            }));      
    }
    ```

Comment: I updated the code. For this line: const mapDispatchToProps => dispatch => ({ getJobs: () => dispatch(jobActions.getJobs()) }); I got this error: TypeError: dispatch is not a function. Did I put in the correct place?

Comment: There is another typo of mine. Please change it to `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ getJobs: () => dispatch(jobActions.getJobs()) });` (notice that => is now =)

Comment: ok, then it's because the first argument is probably a mapStateToProps function that you need to pass in connect() before the mapDispatchToprops. I will update the answer